# How to fadein server control using jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, panel, fadein

I have two webform panels that I display & hide based on a click event in Code Behind.
This is the default state:

```
pnlStepOne.Visible = true;
pnlStepTwo.Visible = false;
```

On a button (#btnStepOne) click event, I currently change the visibility of the panels by switching the visibility values:

```
protected void btnStepOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
pnlStepOne.Visible = false;
pnlStepTwo.Visible = true;
}
```

This part works well. However, I would like to fade in the pnlStepTwo instead of displaying it instantly by changing the visibility settings.

I tried to do this:

```
$("#btnStepOne").click(function (event) {
    $('#pnlStepTwo').fadeIn(3000);
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I assume it's because the pnlStepTwo is not yet visible.

How can I fade in the #pnlStepTwo instead of displaying it instantly?

**EDIT**:

Here's my validation code on pnlStepOne:

```
 $("#<%=btnStepOne.ClientID%>").click(function (event) {

            var fvFname = document.getElementById('fvFname');
            var fvLname = document.getElementById('fvLname');

            ValidatorValidate(fvFname);
            ValidatorValidate(fvLname);

            if (!fvFname.isvalid || !fvLname.isvalid) {
                $("#<%=pnlStepOne.ClientID%>").effect("shake");
            }

            if (fvFname.isvalid && fvLname.isvalid) {

                $('#<%=pnlStepOne.ClientID%>').hide();
                $('#<%=pnlStepTwo.ClientID%>').fadeIn(500);

            }
        });
```

Comment: i have created a sample as per your requirement!

Answer (score 2):

The `Visibility` property of a control **wont allow to render** in a page. Instead use `display:none` using `javascript`.

**Hiding Panel using Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowPanelTwo()
{
  $('#<%=pnlStepOne.ClientID%>').css("display","none");
  //$('#<%=pnlStepTwo.ClientID%>').css("display","block");
  $('#<%=pnlStepTwo.ClientID%>').fadeIn(3000);

}

</script>
```

**Calling from Codebehind:**

```
protected void btnStepOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "uniquekey", "<script type='text/javascript'>ShowPanelTwo();</script>");
}
```

Also you can use:

```
$("#<%=btnStepOne.ClientID%>").click(function (event) {
   $('#<%=btnStepTwo.ClientID%>').fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would do it the JQuery way, as registering the script in the `Click` code behind event is gonna result in an unnecessary round trip.

Comment: So i have also given solution through Jquery too! Registering the Script in code behind by Consideration of the user who posted that if he want to do some serverside operations such as Data Manipulation hence i have given two options you can choose as per your requirement! :)

Comment: Thanks guys for your advice. The code as suggested above by Shekhar works and allows me to fade in and out the panels. However, if I don't use the 'Visible' property and hide the panels via jQuery, the whole form (all textfields on pnlStepOne and pnlStepTwo) are being validated. Which means that if I am on panel one, I can't proceed to the pnlStepTwo without completing the pnlStepOne mandatory fields. That's all good, but once I fade in pnlStepTwo, the textfields (on pnlStepTwo) are already invalid displaying a missing info validation error. Any idea how to address it?

Comment: My validation code on pnlStepOn is provided above in my original post as an Edit

Comment: please explain it more..so i can help u! and if it solves problem please mark as answer!

Comment: Here's what I have: http://www.smithy.somee.com. When you get to Step 2 - Account Information, the username and password textbox have already been validated as invalid before clicking on the Finish button. I assume it's due to a postback. How would I prevent a postback in this case? Thanks!

Comment: please post your html markup & codebhind too in the post for the paanel

Comment: Hi Shekhar,

Markup:
http://www.smithy.somee.com/DefaultMarkup.txt
CodeBehind:
http://www.smithy.somee.com/DefaultCodeBehind.txt

Thanks! :)

Comment: ok i am trying to create sample! I guess you need following:
1.When user is on Step1 first validation must occur is fields valid then show Step2
2. If step2 Form fields Valid then show results on Step3 right? Please let me knw if this is correct and final so i can see into it :) but it will take time 2day m busy...!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52811/discussion-between-shekhar-shete-and-vasek)

Answer (score 1):

The `Visible` property in your C# code will prevent the panel from rendering on the HTML page. So you are correct, your JQuery code cannot see it because it is not yet visible.

I would make `pnlStepTwo` visible and just hide it with `style="display:none"`. You will want to stop your submit button from posting back too, since all it is doing is changing that `Visible` server side property anyway.

Also, to make sure that your client side javascript can see the right element in the DOM, reference it this way:

```
$("#<%=btnStepTwo.ClientID%>")
```

That will make your application return the HTML id for that element as it is actually rendered. Sometimes the rendering engine will return a variation of the server-side ID property, so your client side ID might actually be something like `ContentPlaceHolder1_btnStepTwo`.

Comment: @Vasek As an alternative to using `$("#<%=btnStepTwo.ClientID%>")` you can set the ClientIMode on the control to `Static` which will force it to use the same ID on the client that it's using on the server. Then you can simply do `$("#btnStepTwo")`. You can actually set the default mode to be static from the `web.config` file, see [this excellent article](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/we-lovenet-4-clean-web-control-ids-with-clientidmode-property-to-static-and-predictable).

Comment: You have to be careful using static ID mode, particularly in larger applications. If a control is rendered more than once on a page (it is inside another repeated control like a gridview, or two controls with the same ID in different .ascx's used on the same page) it will not generate unique IDs for those controls, meaning that you have to take care to generate them yourself.